# I need a table cell to be a form to input specific data to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html-table

I have no idea how to explain myself which is why the question isn't even a question. I need to have a table dynamically created from data on mysql (which I've done) but I need to be able to have input in the cells under some of the headings (responsibility, organization, independent work...) When this data is submitted, I need it to be student specific. In other words, when I pull up Johnny Rotten's data, I need to be able to see all the comments under those headings that were submitted (yes this is for teaching). The number of students can vary which is why i need the whole thing to be dynamic. If this is not possible, please let me know. AND if you haven't figured it out already, I am brand new and self-taught!

Here's what I have...

```
<?php

    include 'connect.php';

    if ($db_found) {

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM studentlist WHERE teacher1='smith' OR teacher2 ='smith' OR     
        teacher3='smith' ORDER by homeroom";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);

        echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Homeroom</th>
        <th>Responsibility</th>
        <th>Organization</th>
        <th>Independent Work</th>
        <th>Collaboration</th>
        <th>Initiative</th>
        <th>Self Regulation</th>
        </tr>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['student'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['homeroom'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

    }

    mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: Yes it can be done. You may want to rethink how you thought you were going to do it. You really need to do some howework, here is a starter for 10. `http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php.html` Look at section 4

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've actually been through most of that site as that is where a lot of my self taught came in. I have no problem re-thinking what I am going to do, it's just a matter of how to do it. I've thought about using <div>'s but I still don't know.